# Grouping css tag using pseudo class before (Hover)

Tags: html, css

I am working on Grouping CSS Selector (Hover). I have two text boxes the first one is Username and second one is Password.

When I hover these text field's the icon background has changing the color using transistion.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 login-panel-padng">
    <span class="icon-user">
       <input type="text" class="txt-padding  login-panel-usr-name"     placeholder="Username" />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 login-panel-padng">
 <span class="icon-password">
  <input class="txt-padding login-panel-usr-name" id="txt_pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the code.

```
.icon-user::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f007";
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid lightBlue;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
}
.icon-password::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f084";
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid lightBlue;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition : background 500ms ease-out;
}
.icon-user .icon-password:hover:after {
    background-color: lightBlue;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #336699;
}
```

For the Hover I want to use both icon-user and icon-password class tags. So I can reduce the Number of code line.

Here is the jsfiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/zcmkcuac/)

Kindly help me for this question.

Cheers
Mahadevan

Comment: What do you mean by grouping selector? What problem are you having, and what's your goal?

Comment: `.icon-email` isn't in your markup.

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: For the above three question I have updated my code kindly check

Comment: @Mahadevan You should add the markup to your question.  It's better to not link to a third party site and have your question solely dependent on it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes I will update again with the html code also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group them, why not use the same class on both,

```
...
    <span class="inputIcon icon-user">
        ...
    </span>
...
    <span class="inputIcon icon-password">
        ...
    </span>
...
```

and then,

```
.inputIcon:hover::before { ... }
```

Comment: hi @Kup if i use separate classname  it was working fine but I want the  group tag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I got the solution for the above question.

```
.icon-user:hover::before, .icon-password:hover::before{
   background-color: lightBlue;
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #336699;
 }
```

You have to call all the class like above example. Then the Hover effect will come.

Cheers,
Mahadevan